# Why is this code giving me a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, mingw

Running this code on visual studio code with MINGW compiler and it giving me a segmentation fault

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int *b;
        *b = 20;
    }
```

Comment: To dereference a pointer (`*b`), the pointer must point to a valid object. Currently `b` is uninitialized, so what `b` points at is undefined.

Comment: Please explain why you think it wouldn't so we don't have to guess which part of pointers you misunderstood and so that you don't have to hunt through to find the relevant part of an exaplanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has **undefined behavior**.  `b` is uninitialized, it does not point anywhere meaningful.  So, dereferencing `b` will result in a random memory address, and writing to that memory is crashing your program (but that is not guaranteed, you might just corrupt memory instead).

You need to make `b` point at a valid `int`, eg:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int i;
    int *b = &i;
    *b = 20; // writes to i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your frist Line definer a pointer to int, without setting where it points, so it can point anywhere.

Your second line writers the number 20 into the memory location that b happens to point to, which in your case is a memory location that causes segmentation fault.

What you want is something like int *b = new int(); to allocate a valid memory location for the pointer.